# Why unsplit so slow

Tags: r

I have the following data with ~450 000 rows:

```
'data.frame':   451712 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ mid: int  5732 5732 5732 5732 5732 5732 5732 5732 5732 5732 ...
 $ id : int  25 26 28 29 30 31 33 36 37 38 ...
 $ x  : num  3197 5545 3205 6947 7264 ...
 $ y  : num  6138 5555 6209 5465 5230 ...
 $ t  : Factor w/ 2 levels "C","L": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ r  : Factor w/ 5 levels "Aberrant","Both",..: 3 1 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ c  : num  1 0 1 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 ...
```

Why the following operation takes very long time (> 5 minutes, I stopped execution)

```
 unsplit(split(data, data$mid), data$mid)
```

The `split` itself is fast, but when merging data back it takes forever. If I truncate data to 100 000 rows, then I can get the result in 10 seconds, but as number of rows grows the time increases not lineally.

Comment: Have you checked your RAM allocation? If you chewed up all of it, a lot of swapping will happen, leading to longer execution time. See what happens if you run a loop over `k*1e5` chunks.

Comment: Do you really need to have the data in the same order as before? If not consider just using `do.call(rbind,split(data, data$mid))`, which appears a bit faster in my tests.

Comment: Also, can you add some code to generate data like yours, something like: `n<-1e7;d<-data.frame(d=factor(sample(1:10,n,replace=TRUE)),v=rnorm(n),v2=rnorm(n),v3=rnorm(n))`. I am having a hard time generating data big enough that doesn't complete in 30 seconds.

Comment: Presumably you are doing some `split-apply-combine` style analysis?  If so, have you considered using `data.table` or `dplyr`, as both will likely be way faster?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, RAM usage doesn't grow. Only CPU is used intensively.

Comment: @nograpes, actually, I need the data in exactly the same order. 
You were very close with generated data. Just increase number of different groups from 10 to 2000:
`n<-1e6;d<-data.frame(d=factor(sample(1:2000,n,replace=TRUE)));str(unsplit(split(d, d$d), d$d))`

Comment: @BrodieG, thanks for the hint! I'll look at it. Though, it a bit unusual for me yet to use **ply style functions instead of loops, especially if there is quite complicated logic inside each group.
Nevertheless, it seems strange that such quite a simple operation takes much more time than it should.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it does seem strange, one thing you need to understand with data frames is that they are deathly slow.  Every operation that modifies a data frame is costly, and what `unsplit` is doing is modifying a data frame for each split by re-inserting it.  Something about the internal logic requiring the whole data frame to get copied every time it is modified.  This is called as part of `unsplit`:

```
`split<-.data.frame`
function (x, f, drop = FALSE, ..., value) 
{
    ix <- split(seq_len(nrow(x)), f, drop = drop, ...)
    n <- length(value)
    j <- 0
    for (i in ix) {
        j <- j%%n + 1
        x[i, ] <- value[[j]]
    }
    x
}
<bytecode: 0x7ffd5e282c68>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

`x` here is a data.frame initialized to the size of your result, and you can see that basically we are inserting into it for every split.  Since your data frame is huge, every insert is super costly.  To highlight why this is terrible, consider the following example where we benchmark overwriting each value in a column in a data frame vs. doing the exact same thing with an equivalent matrix.  Even though we're doing exactly the same thing, the data frame version is ~30x slower!  And this is for a tiny data frame.  You can quickly see how this goes to hell when the data.frame is large.

```
df <- data.frame(a=seq(1:100), b=runif(100), c=sample(1:10, 100, rep=T))
mx <- as.matrix(df)

microbenchmark(for(i in 1:nrow(df)) df[i, 2] <- 1)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                                 expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) df[i, 2] <- 1 4.018833 4.273562 4.584293 4.726672 23.46349   100    

microbenchmark(for(i in 1:nrow(mx)) mx[i, 2] <- 1)
# Unit: microseconds
#                                 expr     min       lq   median       uq     max neval
#  for (i in 1:nrow(mx)) mx[i, 2] <- 1 148.304 153.9795 158.5975 163.7065 277.861   100
```

By the way, this is why for the above type of operation the recommendation is to first compute the vector, and at the end replace the vector into the data frame column so that you only modify the data frame once.

Re: using `data.table` or `dplyr`, I challenge you to post as a question the type of analysis you are doing with `split`/`unsplit` and I suspect you'll be surprised by how powerful those packages can be in solving your problems.

Comment: Wow! @BrodieG, thanks for such a comprehensive answer! Now it's clear why the time grows rapidly with increase of number of groups. Will definitely devote some time to learn recommended packages.